# SnippingTool in Windows 7 does not save when pressing the save (diskette) button, nor by selecting "Save-as" under file

Tags: windows-7

Pressing the diskette to save does nothing, nor does selecting save-as from the File menu. X-ing out of the SnippingTool program prompts user to save the file. If "yes" is selected, program terminates (without saving).

Possibly related to this: standard file folders on user accounts do not exist on this machine (e.g., pictures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a folder named `Pictures` to the %USERPROFILE% folder fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/i-cant-save-on-snipping-toolhelp/aa9ffe71-9b5f-43a3-be1e-9ff1cd15a533) running [system file checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) (run command prompt as administrator and type:

> sfc /scannow

, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>) could solve the problem.

Comment: problem persists

Comment: Did you try adding a Pictures folder? The first reply of that thread gives an example how otherwise there is this method: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18583-user-folders-restore-default-location.html